# Trying to find an idiomatic Rust way of calling a series of functions and early out'ing on failure of one

Tags: rust

I would like to condense down a bunch of function calls that occur sequentially, and need to early out so they don't waste more computation later on.

I've been able to get it down to the following, but I am wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this or not.

Here is an MCVE:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    // ...
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(data: &[u8]) -> Option<MyStruct> {
        let result = MyStruct {
            // initialize fields
        };

        // CAN I DO THIS PART BETTER?
        result.process_stuff1()?;
        result.process_stuff2()?;
        // ...
        result.process_stuffn()?;

        Some(result)
    }

    fn process_stuff1(&self) -> Option<()> {
        // ...
        println!("Ran process_stuff1");
        Some(())
    }

    fn process_stuff2(&self) -> Option<()> {
        // ...
        println!("Ran process_stuff2");
        None
    }

    // ...

    fn process_stuffn(&self) -> Option<()> {
        // ...
        println!("Ran process_stuffn");
        Some(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data: [u8; 1] = [0];
    match MyStruct::new(&data[..]) {
        Some(_) => println!("Success"),
        None => println!("Failure")
    }
}
```

with the expected output (I made process_stuff2 fail just to make sure it did in fact short circuit):

> Ran process_stuff1
>
> Ran process_stuff2
>
> Failure

I feel like I'm abusing the language a bit, but it is nicer to read than something like

```
if !result.process_stuff1() {
    None
}

if !result.process_stuff2() {
    None
}

// ...etc
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

I was trying to see if there was some kind of `all(...)` function that I could call.

I am new to Rust so there might be better ways of doing this, and you should not assume I know a lot.

Comment: In C and similar languages the following can work:  result = process_stuff1() && process_stuff2() &&  ...  process_stuffN() ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could use iterators to do this:

```rust
    pub fn new(data: &[u8]) -> Option<MyStruct> {
        let result = MyStruct {
            // initialize fields
        };

        [
            Self::process_stuff1,
            Self::process_stuff2,
            Self::process_stuffn,
        ]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|f| f(&result))
        .collect::<Option<()>>()?;

        Some(result)
    }
```

The reason this works is that `FromIterator` (the trait `collect()` uses) is implemented for `Option` as an early exit (aborting iteration), and is implemented for `()` to just return `()` (any number of `()`s become `()`).

However, I wouldn't recommend actually writing this code — it is *less clear* than what you have, and more concise unless you have a *lot* more functions to call. I think you should keep the code structure you have, unless there is some way to express your multiple functions as, say, one function with different parameters.

---

One thing I do think you should consider changing is returning a `Result` instead of an `Option`. The logic with `?` is exactly the same, but you can return an "error" value reporting *which* of the sequence of functions failed. This can be key to efficiently diagnosing either program bugs or problems with the input data. (Of course, this may be unnecessary for reasons in your actual application, like obvious side effects of each function.)

Comment: Please note, questions involving code stub code and/or MCVE's are often off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.